# Scala code for filtering a xml file based on a date

Tags: xml, scala

I have a XML file for which I need to filter data based on a creation date timestamp. I need also to collect the names of the users. I used the below scala query to get the task done.

```
val names = userElems.map(u => (u \ "@DisplayName").text).filter(_._ \"@CreationDate" > "2013-01-01T01:00:00.000")
```

Map part alone is working but I am not able to filter the data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code

Created a small example.

```
val foo = <foo><bar type="greet" date="2015-01-01T01:00:00.000">hi</bar>
               <bar date="2012-01-01T01:00:00.000" type="count">1</bar>
               <bar date="2014-01-01T01:00:00.000" type="color">yellow</bar>
          </foo>

val bars = foo \ "bar"
bars.filter(s => (s \ "@date").exists(t => t.text > "2013-01-01T01:00:00.000")).map(u => (u \ "@type").text)
```

First just extracting all bar from foo, then filter after date and map to the type.

## Output

```
List(greet, color)
```

## Your Code

So for you it should be something like

```
val names = userElems.filter(s => (s \ "@CreationDate").exists(t => t.text > "2013-01-01T01:00:00.000")).map(u => (u \ "@DisplayName").text)
```

Comment: @VSriSandeep could you please accept my answer then? thanks?